# c equivalent of ucomisd

Tags: c, x86

While porting a windows binary to linux, I have come across the following set of instructions:

```
ucomisd xmm5,xmm0
lahf 
test ah,0x44
jp 0x42D511
```

From what I can tell it is comparing the two values in `ucomisd`, then testing for the presence of either the `ZF` or `PF` flags, but not both.

What would the `c` equivalent be? Every search I do on the topic results in comparing float/double with an epsilon, which this clearly isn't doing.

If it helps, the second operand is always a const value taken from the .rdata section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [pseudo for ucomisd](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/UCOMISD.html) seems to be

```
RESULT← UnorderedCompare(DEST[63:0] <> SRC[63:0]) {
(* Set EFLAGS *) CASE (RESULT) OF
    UNORDERED: ZF,PF,CF←111;
    GREATER_THAN: ZF,PF,CF←000;
    LESS_THAN: ZF,PF,CF←001;
    EQUAL: ZF,PF,CF←100;
ESAC;
OF, AF, SF←0; }
```

I.e. `ZF xor PF` would be true if the 2 double-precision operands are equal. If I read correctly this would be

```
double a, b;

if (a == b) {
    ...
}
```

There is no **jump if zero and parity flag unset** opcode, which is why the `lahf` + `test` or some alternative means are required.

Testing this function:

```
int x(double a, double b) {
    return a == b;
}
```

with GCC produces

```
xorl    %eax, %eax
movl    $0, %edx
ucomisd %xmm1, %xmm0

# set al to 1 if no parity flag
setnp   %al

# if zero flag not set, zero the return value
cmovne  %edx, %eax

ret
```

i.e. return 1 if no parity flag and equal.

Comment: Thanks, I switched the compiler to MSVC and it produced the original content. I had my head wrapped up in all the `std::isunordered` `std::isnan` functions...

Comment: @Twifty: interesting.  https://godbolt.org/z/1KQUDt.  (I used a conditional store to force compilers to branch instead of branchless).  MSVC does indeed use lahf/test in 32-bit code, but when making 64-bit code, it does the same thing as gcc (`ucomisd` / `jp` / `jne`).  One or the other is a missed-optimization.  (Also, gcc should probably `jp` / `sete` for Antti's function; branching on unordered should predict well, and simplify the branchless handling of the ordered cases.)

Comment: Before working on this project, I would never question the compiler. But now, after wading through the generated instructions, I'm left thinking "what?". So many over complicated steps of doing a simple task.

Comment: I think that `lahf` + `test` is rather clever... It is the microprocessor architecture itself that makes this complicated :D why not have flags as a general register that you could and/or against as you wish